# Text file generator using Python

Tags: python, file, scripting-language

I have 3 files-
file1:

```
A
B
C
```

file2:

```
10,20,30,40
40,20,50,60
60,20,80,90
```

file3:

```
20
30
40
```

How do I merge the files to generate a single file in the form:

```
A  10,20,30,40  20
B  40,20,50,60  30
C  60,20,80,90  40
```

**Where every column is separated by a '\t',that is,a tab and Not a space.**
 I'm really new to Python and I'm not sure how to implement this. I have seen various examples on the net where they simply concatenate the files without preserving the pattern(column). 
How do I preserve the pattern by separating the columns with a single tab character?
Any relevant code would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no indication of an attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's easy enough to do this in Python, there's a standard unix tool to do it as well. Just do `paste file1 file2 file3 > singlefile`.

The same job within Python could be something like:

```
import itertools
def paste(outfile, separator="\t", *infiles):
    for line in itertools.izip_longest(*infiles, fillvalue=""):
        outfile.write(separator.join(column.rstrip("\n") for column in line)+"\n")
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    paste(sys.stdout, "\t", *map(open,sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score 5):

That's a good job for [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

Assuming `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are handles to your input files, and `output` is a handle to your output, you can do

```
for items in zip(*(f1, f2, f3)):
    output.write("\t".join(item.strip() for item in items) + "\n")
```

`zip()` zips all corresponding items (all the first lines, second lines, etc.) together, presenting them as a tuple.

`join()` joins them into a string, using `\t` as a separator.

Since we've read the lines from a file, they mostly end in `\n`, so we need to strip those before joining the strings.

Comment: Nice to see Python's philosophy of providing a fairly obvious way to do things working out. I see significant similarities in our approaches. :)